# GPU makes noises based on the rendering load

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, noise, opengl

It's a weird problem.

I've got a really basic OpenGL app where I just render a cube and move around in space. So, when I start the program, I get a high-pitched noise from the GPU. And what is really weird is when my camera comes close to the mesh, the noise become more high-pitched gradually and when I move back it becomes less high-pitched. It's literally like I am turning a pitch knob on an oscillator back and forth.

I also tried to load the gpu with a few games. When I start dota2, while I am in a menu I also get this noise. Later on in the game it disappears (or becomes negligible).

I've got a pretty new laptop with GTX1650 GPU that I've been using for about an year and it's a first time I encounter this problem. I am saying it's GPU, but it may be something else to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

The problem sounds like
[Coil Whine](https://xoticpc.com/blogs/news/what-is-coil-whine)
which can occur in any array of PC components,
but it typically occurs when you start up an especially taxing program.

PC components have a resonant frequency when coupled with the rest of the
electrical circuit.
Coil Whine is caused by electromagnetic coils that act as inductors or
transformers.
Though it can come from many components, it is usually found in high-end
video cards.
Noise can also occur when the coil is poorly secured to the circuit board.

One thing you can do is double check all screws to ensure that they are tight,
or try to move components away from the GPU or better isolate electrical wires
that pass near it.

If the noise is unavoidable, you could better sound-isolate your computer case,
or even change the video card.